# OpenLayers ZoomSlider doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, openlayers

So here I create a map using OpenLayers:

```js
var map;
var mapLat = 0;
var mapLng = 0;
var mapDefaultZoom = 14;
var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng, mapLat]),
    zoom: mapDefaultZoom
});
var oldLayer;
function initMap() {
    map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'theMap',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    url: 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                })
            })
        ],
        view: view
    });
    map.addControl(new ol.control.ZoomSlider());
}
```

But for some reason the ZoomSlider will not render on the map. Is there some sort of initialization I need to do on it, say, to give it a size and position? Or am I instantiating it the wrong way? I tried using an import statement `import ZoomSlider from 'ol/control/ZoomSlider';` or something like that but I only got an error...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the correct styles via ol.css which will position the Zoom slider correctly.

See example here based on your code above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ol-zoom-slider

Note the styles reference in index.html